# Сравнение масивов с обьектами и выборка

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с обьектами "товаров" например.

```
someArr = [{name:***, prodid:***, prodinfo:***},{name:***, prodid:***, prodinfo:***}]
```

И больше в нем инфы разной.
Есть еще один массив

```
someOtherArr = [{prodid:***},{prodid:***},{prodid:***}]
```

в нем только объекты с айди.
как сравнить эти массивы и выбрать с someArr только те обьекты где есть айди с someOtherArr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем во втором массиве объекты, если они содержат только одно поле? Почему бы не превратить `someOtherArr` в `[prodid1, prodid2, prodid3, ...]`, тогда фильтрация в одну строку реализуется

Синтаксис es6

```
const someArr = [{name:***, prodid:***, prodinfo:***}, ...]
const someOtherArr = [prodid, prodid, prodid]

const filtredArr = someArr.filter(el => someOtherArr.includes(el.prodid))
```

`includes` как раз проверяет есть ли элемент в массиве, если да возвращает `true`

Если все таки структуру `someOtherArr` поменять изначально нельзя, то поменяем ее руками

```
const someArr = [{name:***, prodid:***, prodinfo:***}, ...]
const someOtherArr = [{prodid}, {prodid}, {prodid}]

// содержит значения prodid
const mapedOtherArr = someOtherArr.map(el => el.prodid)
const filtredArr = someArr.filter(el => mapedOtherArr.includes(el.prodid))
```

Comment: спасибо. тоже пригодилось. использовал для других целей момент с переводом массива в такой вид const someOtherArr = [prodid, prodid, prodid]

уверен что в остальном ваш вариант тоже рабочий просто мне он был сложнее к реализации. на тот момент

Comment: еще раз спасибо. воспользоавался. способ супер

Answer (score 2):

Вариант много. Вот 1 из них.

```js
var someArr = [
  {name:"name1", prodid:1, prodinfo:''},
  {name:"name2", prodid:2, prodinfo:''},
   {name:"name3", prodid:3, prodinfo:''},
 {name:"name4", prodid:4, prodinfo:''},
];
  
  var someOtherArr = [
  {prodid:1},
  {prodid:3},
  {prodid:2}
  ]

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < someOtherArr.length; i++) {
  result.push(someArr.find(function (item) {
      return item.prodid == someOtherArr[i].prodid
   }))
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помогло.